# Have to set different file owner to differenct apache vhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I have `vhost1`,`vhost2` under Apache.
Do I need to set `/var/www/vhost1`'s file owner to `vhostuser1`,set  `/var/www/vhost2`'s file owner to `vhostuser2`.
Somebody said it's the necessary setting for security,suppose `vhost1`was hacked,`vhost2` will not be affected.

Comment: That setup won't *hurt* anything (though it may yield problems/no benefit if the `apache2` user needs write access under webroot). You'd be best-served by starting with [Hardening Apache](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache/Hardening), IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is *not* using dedicated user/group settings for each vhost `DocumentRoot`; rather, the key point is that, by default, the `httpd` process runs with the **same** permission for **all** your virtualhost. This means that a rogue `php` script under `vhost1` can read all `vhost2` files.

A solution is to run each `httpd` process under specific user permissions. This is done via the [`apache-mpm-itk` module](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/). With this module, you can specify the user/group under which a single vhost will run. Combining that with restrictive permissions on the filesystem/DocumentRoot side, you can effectively prevent a compromised vhost to alter/spy other sites hosted on the same server.

Other, more heavy-weight approaches:

- run each `httpd` process under its chroot;
- do extended use of Linux VPS / containers to create a dedicate instance for each site.

Comment: if I set `php_admin_value open_basedir` in apache conf,can rogue php read `vhost2` file?

Comment: If no,I need not set dedicated user/group for each vhost?

Comment: @kittygirl `open_basedir` will protect you from php files only. Perl, python, cgi, etc. scripts remain a security concern.

Comment: How to `run each httpd process under its chroot`?

Comment: @kittygirl `chroot` done well is a complex task, whose explanation goes beyond what can be described here. I do not suggest to run a chrooted service unless you very well understand all the implications.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not mandatory, but it makes a LOT of sense if you deployed a server multiple users have access to. If you want to do this you would have to work with suexec, which executes cgi scripts as the respective user instead of the default www-data user.

This setup is mostly used if you have a webserver that is shared amongst multiple users and you want to keep them from accessing/manipulating each other's data (e.g. when they can run their own php scripts).

And also it increases security a bit since it does the same if one of your sites got hacked and malicious code was run on your site, at least your other sites will not be affected.

Downside is you have to keep track of all users/folders.